# What is required to relocate a garbage disposal?

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

I have a garbage disposal in my two well sink, only problem is when it was installed, it was placed on the left side of the sink -- closest to the dishwasher, further from the stove. When I'm cooking, which I do frequently, I abuse the right side of the sink constantly rinsing and clearing plates and tools of food into it, since it's closest to where I'm working.

[image]

Aside from learning how to cope with a disposal being too far away, is it fiesable to move the disposal to the other side of the sink, will it fit, if it will what types of tools will I need to complete the job.

[image]

[image]

I'm assuming, if it is possible, I'll need to re-cut some of the pipework to fit the new setup, though I imagine I'll be able to salvage most of the current joints.

Comment: you should be able to mirror the entire setup with minimal difficulty at first glance (make sure the drain from the disposal has minimal bends though)

Comment: Plumbing, nothing like the sound of cussing in the morning.

Answer (score 6):

This project is fairly straight forward. You need to completely disassemble both sides including the in sink trims.  You will need an adjustable wrench, a large pair of pump pliers or monkey wrench, screwdriver, nothing special.  Be sure the electrical wire will reach the new disposal location, it not, you will need a j-box and some wire,  you will also need some plumber's putty to seat the drain trims.  You definitely will have to replumb the drains and traps, but you may be able to salvage a few pieces.  It's gonna take you a few hours so be prepared to spend the day without water in the kitchen.

Comment: Forgive me if I seem a bit naïve, but most of the plumbing "screws off", would it be relatively safe to assume that, since the wells are equal distant apart and the main pipe is almost dead center with the sink, that I would just "move" the disposal then re-configure the plumbing in a mirror of it's current setup? Again, not quite sure if it's possible that way.

Comment: If the main pipe *is* dead center, then you should be able to swap the existing bits; if it doesn't go back together, you're stuck without a sink until you make a trip to the hardware store. So, buy the replacement pipe & fittings first, and return them if you don't need them.

My plumber has a step van to carry around all the fittings he might need.

Comment: If you are out and about often then you should at least buy some replacement parts.  They are not expensive and if you do need them you have them.  If you don't buy them then that guarantees the fact that you will need them.